# Export icons/links are not shown in p:dataTable header

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I checked the [export sample](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/dataexporter/basic.xhtml) and it works fine. Then I copied the code from there and now the beginning of my data table looks like this:

```
<p:dataTable id="dtResults" var="rule" value="#{ruleCollection}" paginator="true" rows="30" paginatorTemplate="{RowsPerPageDropdown} {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {CurrentPageReport} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {Exporters}"
                 rowsPerPageTemplate="30,50,100,500" lazy="true">

<f:facet name="{Exporters}">
    <h:commandLink>
        <p:graphicImage name="/demo/images/excel.png" width="24" />
        <p:dataExporter type="xls" target="dtResults" fileName="rules" />
    </h:commandLink>
</f:facet>
```

This is what I get:

[image: Expecting export link]

`/demo/images/excel.png` is not there so I also tried this instead of `p:graphicImage`:

```
<h:outputText value="export" />
```

But the result is the same. My configuration is:

- Tomcat 7.0.53
- Mojarra 2.2.6
- primefaces-5.0.jar
- JRE 1.8.0_05
- IE8

I have POI installed and working but I also tried with `type="csv"` and the result is the same. What could be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The option for customization template is available in version 5.1 community. Stable release does not exist yet but you can download the [snapshot of development version](https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/org/primefaces/primefaces/5.1-SNAPSHOT/). The current snapshot is from May-25 and does not have this feature.

[The feature is included](https://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/detail?id=6999) in version 5.0.2 which is available to [Elite users](http://www.primefaces.org/support). "1 year Elite subscription is 249$ per developer.".

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Stack Overflow! Thanks for this answer... note: this is not my subject area, so I can't tell if this answers the question or not. Can you expand on this to explain what the Original Poster could do to solve their problem (ie don't just say why they can't do it, give us some ideas for what they could do instead)? thanks!